# How to navigate from a content page to the second tab of Tabbed page in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, frontend

I want to navigate from my Content Page to second tab on the Tabbed Page.Please say how can I do it

```
 <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:MoneyExchangeMainScreen Title="home" IconImageSource="cehome" />
        <local:ExchangeWallet Title="wallet" IconImageSource="cewallet" />
        <NavigationPage Title="prices" IconImageSource="ceprices">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:MoneyExchangePrice />
            </x:Arguments>

        </NavigationPage>
        <local:ExchangePage Title="exchange" IconImageSource="ceexchange" />
        <local:ExchangePage Title="settings" IconImageSource="cesetting" />
    </TabbedPage.Children>
```

Comment: which ContentPage?  One contained within the tabs, or elsewhere?

Comment: This page is not on tabs. In general, the idea is that the user should login (separate content page) and then he should go to the second tab on the tabbed page

Comment: set the tabbed page as the App's MainPage, and set the tab's CurrentPage property to the tab that you want displayed

Comment: What if I want to get to the second tab from one page, and later after the transaction (as well as a separate content page) I want to get to the third tab?

Comment: then change the CurrentPage property again.  But I would question this design - programatically jumping between tabs isn't generally a great idea

Comment: Can you show me some code to do it,please?

Comment: I think Jason means something like `yourTabbedPage.SelectedItem = theTabYouWannaShow`

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Set Tabbedpage as `App.MainPage`, and manually set its `CurrentPage`  .

#### Somewhere in separate content page

```
 YourTabbed tab = new YourTabbed();
 tab.CurrentPage = tab.Children[1];    //this means going to second tab
 (App.Current as App).MainPage = tab;
```